# How do I do a schema only backup and restore in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

How do I take a schema level backup in PostgreSQL database and restore on the another database? Is there any single command available for this? For example, can I pg_dump and restore in single line?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
pg_dump --schema=masters oldDB > masters1.sql
cat masters1.sql | psql newDB
```

or

in single command you can do by this

```
pg_dump oldDB --schema masters  | psql -h localhost newDB;
```

Comment: Your solution dumps data as well as schema.

Comment: @Bogolt The commands dumps a single schema as in "public" is a schema (so schema as a namespace in database). Not schema as is in `CREATE TABLE` kind of things (so not structure). There is this ambiguity in English unfortunately. It's still a valid answer though. The user didn't said which context he means.

Answer (score 41):

Backup schema and restore it on system for postgresql as below:

Dump schema for database

```
pg_dump -s database_name > db.sql
```

Dump schema for specific table

```
pg_dump -s database_name -t table_name > db.sql
```

Restore backed up schema using below command

```
psql -d database_name -h localhost -U postgres < path/db.sql
```

Comment: Just a note that this only dumps structure (no data), but for a whole database. This is not for a single schema (namespace within database).

Answer (score 7):

`-s` or `--schema-only` to exclude data from dump
[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-pgdump.html)

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html)?

Example from the manual:

> To dump all schemas whose names start with east or west and end in
>   gsm, excluding any schemas whose names contain the word test:
>
> $ pg_dump -n 'east*gsm' -n 'west*gsm' -N '*test*' mydb > db.sql

Comment: actually i need in single line for both backup and restore

Comment: Again, this command dumps matching schemas, including the non-blob data contained therein. You need `--schema-only` to exclude data.

Comment: What's wrong with documentation for many people: documentation can take a relatively long while to wade through, whereas SE can get an answer quickly.  For a quick task like backing up a DB reading the docs is annoying and tedious, especially when those docs are as daunting as postgres'