# Postgresql - pg_dump - no matching schemas were found

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, pg-dump

I'm trying to create a backup from PostgreSQL database, but getting the following error: pg_dump: No matching schemas were found

I'm logged in as root and running the command

pg_dump -f db.dump --format=plain --schema=existing_schema --username=userx --host=localhost databasename

1. I logged in with userx to psql and tried \dt - this gave me information, that schema with name existing_schema is public.
2. I checked \l to see that databasename is the database name.
3. Password is correct, otherwise I could not access psql.
4. Localhost is correct, checked from running processes. Tried the ip-address of the server also, but in this case pg_admin gave an error about the host address.

Output of \dl:

```
 
                  List of relations

Schema |                Name                 | Type  | Owner
--------+-------------------------------------+-------+-------
 public | existing_schema                    | table | userx
```

Comment: "*schema with name existing_schema is public*" that doesn't make sense. Is that schema schema named `public` or is it named `existing_schema`?

Comment: That means, that if I enter the command \dt, I'll get the result:
Schema | Name | Type  | Owner :::
public | existing_schema | table | userx

Comment: "*Owner public*" is not something the `\dt` command would display.

Comment: It displays Schema : public | Name : existing_schema | Type : table | Owner : userx. Schema, Name, Type and Owner are column headers and public, existing_schema, table, userx are column values in one row. Tried to put them under eachother, but didn't work in comment, sorry.

Comment: Can you add the output (copy & paste) to your question? (enclose it in `<pre>` tags)

Comment: Why are you running these as root and not as postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **schema**'s name is `public`.

`existing_schema` is the name of a table in the schema public.

It's not clear from your pg_dump commandline what you want to do.

If you want to export *all tables* from the *schema* `public` you need to specify:

```
--schema=public
```

If you want to export *only* the table `existing_schema` then you need to specify:

```
--table=existing_schema
```

Answer (score 14):

You can try with back slash and double quote as metioned [here](http://postgresql.nabble.com/pg-dump-t-quot-Table-quot-for-cmd-exe-td5731755.html).

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump -v Database_Name -t "\"Table_Name\""
```

Answer (score 5):

For future googlers, in my case my schema had dots ("my.schema"), and the proper way to address this is by escaping:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d mydatabase --schema \"my.schema\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      \dn list out all the schema in the database
```

if you want to dump only schema ,

[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564777/schema-only-backup-and-restore-in-postgresql/12564792#12564792)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the schema name was upper case and no matter what I tried (`-n MYSCHEMA`, `-n "MYSCHEMA"`, `-n "\"MYSCHEMA\""`) it did not work until I renamed the schema to "myschema" in the database. Then I could dump with all of `-n MYSCHEMA`, `-n "MYSCHEMA"`, and `-n "\"MYSCHEMA\""`.

It looks like pg_dump internally uses lower case, that means it doesn't quote the schema name given in the command line.

However when calling pg_dump with `-n """MYSCHEMA"""` it works.

When adding a table name however the option -n did not work anymore for me. If schema and table-name contains capitalized letters, I used this:

`pg_dump -f file.txt -t \"MySchema\".\"MyTable\"`.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me --schema "\"your_schema\""